# Gas estimation failed while trying to deploy a smart contract on remix

Tags: solidity, remix, blockchain

I tried to deploy this solidity code on Remix

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

// Import ChainlinkClient from the Chainlink library
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract EmailVerification is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
    address public owner;
    bytes32 public jobId;
    uint256 public fee;
    string public emailServiceURL;
    string public apiKey;

    event VerificationRequested(address indexed user, string email);
    event VerificationCompleted(address indexed user);

    constructor() {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        setChainlinkOracle(0x40193c8518BB267228Fc409a613bDbD8eC5a97b3);
        jobId = '7da2702f37fd48e5b1b9a5715e3509b6';
        fee = (1 * LINK_DIVISIBILITY) / 10;
        emailServiceURL = 'url';
        apiKey = 'my-api-key';
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function requestVerification(string memory recipientEmail) public {
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(
            jobId,
            address(this),
            this.fulfill.selector
        );
        string memory subject = "Email Verification";
        string memory message = "Please click the verification link to confirm your email.";
        req.add("to", recipientEmail);
        req.add("subject", subject);
        req.add("message", message);
        req.add("url", emailServiceURL);
        req.add("apikey", apiKey);
        sendChainlinkRequestTo(chainlinkOracleAddress(), req, fee);
        emit VerificationRequested(msg.sender, recipientEmail);
    }

    function fulfill(bytes32 requestId) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(requestId) {
        // Handle email service response and confirm verification
        // Emit an event to signify verification completion
        emit VerificationCompleted(msg.sender);
    }

    // Helper function to convert bytes32 to string
    function bytes32ToString(bytes32 _bytes32) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory bytesString = new bytes(32);
        uint charCount = 0;
        for (uint j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
            uint8 character = uint8(uint256(_bytes32) * uint256(2) ** (8 * j));
            if (character != 0) {
                bytesString[charCount] = bytes1(character);
                charCount++;
            }
        }
        bytes memory bytesStringTrimmed = new bytes(charCount);
        for (uint j = 0; j < charCount; j++) {
            bytesStringTrimmed[j] = bytesString[j];
        }
        return string(bytesStringTrimmed);
    }

  receive() external payable {}

     
}
```

But I am getting this warning message from Remix

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
> Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","id":1970708253356763}

And the transaction fails if I try to send it like that. I have tried increasing the gas limit but it's still not working.

Any suggestion on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error is coming because of `setPublicChainlinkToken();`. Maybe check the docs or reach out to the community. I am not free right now to figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setChainlinkToken(address)` instead of `setPublicChainlinkToken()`
setChainlinkToken takes address of deployed instance of LINK token.
you can find the addresses of deployed link tokens [here](https://docs.chain.link/resources/link-token-contracts)

if you use `setPublicChainlinkToken()` it will use a link tokens pointer contract address which will not be deployed in your local remix.